# Time complexity of the recursive pseudocode

Tags: performance, algorithm, time-complexity

What would be the time complexity function for the pseudocode?

```
int what(int k){
   if(k==0 || k==1) 
      return k;
   else 
      return what(k-1)*what(k-2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While the number of calls increases (asymptotically) at the Golden Ratio as k increases, it is not the Fibonacci sequence. The number of calls to what() made for n starting at 0 is:
1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 15. As well, the function what(k) is k: -> Fib(k).

That all clarified, the complexity remains O(Fib(n)), as stated earlier.

Comment: can you please show me the step for multiplication (*) of two function which is addition (+) in fibo series like -> fib(k-1) + fib(k-2)

Comment: @fean: I am not following your question. Can you expand?

Comment: are there any difference between * and + when they situate in middle of two same recursive function like "fib(..) */+ fib(..)" , if yes then in my code there is a * operator instead of + which is not like Fibonacci series.

Answer (score 0):

That function doesn't compute the Fibonacci sequence, but the number of calls IS the Fibonacci sequence.

Since the function doesn't do any work to speak of internally, the time complexity is the same as the number of calls.

So it is `O(fib N)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the time complexity for this code is **O(n!)**, since number of calls multiplies each **k** increment (this is very very bad).

(Joke) But i have good news! This code can be simplified into **O(1)** since it always return 0!

```
int what(int k) { return 0; }
```